# Gradle: Exclude/Include test classes that extend a specific class

Tags: java, gradle, junit

In my project there are 2 types of tests: simple unit tests and acceptance tests with UI automation. All acceptance tests are extending a common base class:

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class MyAcceptanceTest extends AbstractAcceptanceTest {
    @Test
    public void someTest() {...}
}
```

Is it possible with gradle to filter tests so that only the acceptance tests are executed?

My main goal is that with `gradle build` only the normal unit tests are executed (all test classes except those that extend from `AbstractAcceptanceTest`).

The second goal is to have a separate task that only executes the acceptance tests (only test classes that extend `AbstractAcceptanceTest`). However, it would also be ok to execute all tests with this task (no filtering).

As far as I've found in the docs and by googling, filtering is only possible by file name patterns. But maybe there is some groovy magic that allows filtering like this?

EDIT

I've found a solution that works but feels a little hacky:
I've added a `@Category` annotation from JUnit to the base class (`AbstractAcceptanceTest`). The category needs an identifier class for which I've created a class `com.example.AcceptanceTest`. In my gradle.build file I'm using this configuration:

```
task acceptanceTests (type: Test) {
    test {
        useJUnit {
            includeCategories 'com.example.AcceptanceTest'
        }
    }
}


test {
    useJUnit {
        excludeCategories 'com.example.AcceptanceTest'
    }
}
```

This way the acceptance tests aren't executed in normal build but only with `gradle acceptanceTests`.

Comment: Are those two types of tests not organized into separate packages? If yes you could use that for filtering?

Comment: No, they aren't organized in separate packages. There is no pattern in the packages or file names that could be used to distinguish the tests.

Comment: Any solution identified for this? I have the same exact inquiry.